# Keeping Leading Zeros in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I need to keep leading zerod in a textbox that will be used to input data into a database. It is for SKU Numbers. I need to be able to type in leading zeros (ex. 001234567890) and then input them into the database.

However I can't figure out how to keep the leading zeros in a double. I do not need it in a string format but in a double. Is there a way to do this while keeping it a number and not a string?

EX.

```
txtProductBarcode.Text = Format(txtProductBarcode.Text, "############")
'This does not work
```

Comment: You've tagged this with 3 different languages: you might want to narrow it down a little...

Comment: It is vb.net.  I included those because I know sometimes the code can be the same.

Comment: If you need the leading zeros, it's usually best to keep it as a string.  Is/was there a reason you wanted to keep it as a double?

Answer (score 1):

Using `0` in place of `#` will cause leading zeros to be output.

For example:

```
Dim s as string = string.Format("{0:000###}", 12345d)
Console.WriteLine(s)
```

will output

```
012345
```

See [Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx#Y1076) on MSDN.

BTW, not sure why you are worried about keeping the leading zeros whilst "as a double".  The double is just a double, and formatting for display shouldn't matter.  0123 is the same as 123, otherwise you should be using a string datatype and not a double.

Comment: I need it a double because I am using that input and adding it to a database table. That column is a double. I am not just displaying it.

Comment: So.....you want to keep the leading zeros in the database, but keep the datatype as a double?

Comment: I changed it I didn't want to redo my whole database but I fix it.

Comment: @daniel.porter what database server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this is one.
You can convert the integer num to double.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim num As Integer
    Dim temp As String = ""
    Try
       If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
          num = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
          If num <> 0 then
             TextBox1.Text = num.ToString("D6")
             temp = num
          else
             TextBox1.ReadOnly = False
          End If
          If num.Length = 6 Then
             TextBox1.ReadOnly = True
             TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
          ElseIf num = 0 Then
             TextBox1.ReadOnly = False
          End If
          TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
       End If
    Catch ex As Exception
       Msgbox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```